# Spring CRUD: how to handle null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I currently use a Spring (Boot) CrudRepository interface to fetch my Hibernate entities, in the context of this question the `findOne(Long id)` method.

This all works fine as long as I do not call this with null as id, in which case the generated method terminates with a NullPointerException. Now I could easily warp another class around that function to handle that, but that would kinda defy the concept of the automated CRUD system.

Is there a way to get the generated Spring code to handle `null` IDs in a way that `null` is returned instead of an exception?

To be more clear: I have code wrapped around that to prevent the exception. The question is specifically if there is a *Spring* way to handle that instead of wrapping code around it.

Comment: well from javadoc its clearly specified they won't accept null input parameter, so why would a null check before calling findOne() defy the concept of the CRUD system?

Comment: Problem is that I use MapStruct to generate Entities from XML and MapStruct does not check for null beforehand. And it actually shouldn't as my code would have to define what to do on null. However I can't because that code above is also generated.

Comment: Then maybe MapStruct isn't the best tool for your task?

Comment: MapStruct is probably the best tool currently available for mapping Objects. I simply added a new converter from Long to my Entity to the definition that does the null check and then calls findOne and MapStruct automagically switched to use that function instead. 

However I think Spring should be a bit more null-resilliant here. I hoped that there was just some way to configure that, but according to what Zeromus wrote there probably isn't any way to do that.

Comment: @Zeromus Having null as ID is a common case, when creating entities from an external source like XML or JSON, that indicates that for an optional relation there is no linked entity. So everyone who transforms from XML to Entity will have to write those null checks. The Spring CRUD system is designed to avoid common boilerplate code, which it does wonderfully, except for the null check issue.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Look at [the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findOne-ID-).

> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if id is null

The logic of findOne is simple :

- it returns null if it can't find an Object with the specified id
- it throws an exception if the caller don't know the id (i.e. if the caller gives a null argument).

The problem is in the code calling 'findOne', so you should try to fix that.

---

(edit after question has changed).

(note that this is not precisely a "Spring way" to change the behavior of the Repository, it's a "way" to move your wrapping code at a lower level)

You can look at [AOP with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice).

You can use an @Advice @Around the findOne method to catch the IllegalArgumentException (or even better: test for null arg and return null immediatelly).

Something like this:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class AroundExample {

    @Around("com.xyz.myapp.MyRepository.findOne() && args(id)")
    public Object hackFindOne(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Object id) throws Throwable {
        if(id==null) return null;
        return pjp.proceed();
    }

}
```

Comment: As I wrote in the other question: I already have code wrapped around it, I know how to solve that. The question is if Spring has any feature to avoid having to wrap code around that.